# Change image by key arrows is not working.

Tags: javascript

I created function to change images by clickiking arrows. 
My functions is not working. Can you give me some hints?

You can find my code below:

```js
var imgs = [
  "assets/1.jpg",
  "assets/2.jpg",
  "assets/3.jpg",
  "assets/4.jpg",
  "assets/5.jpg",
  "assets/6.jpg",
  "assets/7.jpg"

];


function changeImage() {
  var img = document.getElementById("images");
  img_index = ++img_index % 7;
  img.src = imgs[img_index];
}


function checkKey(e) {

  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == '37') {
    // left arrow
    changeImage();
  } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    // right arrow
    changeImage();
  }

}

// document.onkeydown = checkKey();
```

```html
<img id="images" src="assets/1.jpg" />
```

Thank you, 
Megi

Comment: What is not working. Do you get an error? Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ;)

Comment: try with this line (uncommented): `document.onkeydown = checkKey;`

Comment: Imgaes are not change, thank you

Comment: when I uncommented document.onkeydown = checkKey; I got inf - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined
    at checkKey (script11.js:55)
    at script11.js:65"

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems with your script.

- Remove the `()` on the end of this line `document.onkeydown = checkKey();`. Like you did it you will directly call the function instead of assignin it to the event.
- The `img_index` value is not defined in your example and therefore it fails. You could just set it to `0` at the start.

```js
var img_index = 0;
var imgs = [
  "assets/1.jpg",
  "assets/2.jpg",
  "assets/3.jpg",
  "assets/4.jpg",
  "assets/5.jpg",
  "assets/6.jpg",
  "assets/7.jpg"

];


function changeImage() {
  var img = document.getElementById("images");
  img_index = ++img_index % 7;
  img.src = imgs[img_index];
}


function checkKey(e) {

  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == '37') {
    // left arrow
    changeImage();
  } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    // right arrow
    changeImage();
  }

}

document.onkeydown = checkKey;
```

```html
<img id="images" src="assets/1.jpg" />
```

Comment: NtFreX - Thank you, now the code is  understandable for me ;)